# C# .NET Application Settings and Upgrading

Tags: c#, .net, settings

I use Settings.Default.MySettingName & Settings.Default.Save to save and load settings. When I change my version number how am I able to get the settings from the old version and apply to them my new version? I just can't quite figure it out.

Comment: How do you mean old settings? From where?

Comment: @Oded: the settings are stored in a folder structure that contains the version.

Comment: @Henk - thanks for clarifying. I never use `Settings` myself...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Settings.Upgrade() looks like it has some promise - check out [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/30b6314e-2e4f-4ff3-871c-ad58206b512d) - and note that this method should be called once-and-only-once by your application.

Comment: No problem - glad to hear it, Luke.