# User settings - different location for each application version?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm developing an application that saves various user settings (e.g. window locations, options, preferences). This is done using the syntax

```
Properties.Settings.Default.setting_name = "xxx";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

and

```
var x = Properties.Settings.Default.setting_name;
```

Here is an example of the underlying settings file path:-

> C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\company_name\exe_name.vsh_Url_kxrjspzszls01bmlnkpeuf5cutfdioia\1.0.0.0

The problem is that each time I build and release a new version of the software, users are losing their settings. This is presumably down to the fact that the application exe version number is being included in the file path, so each time a new version is installed it starts over with a new, empty settings folder? Fortunately we're still in the dev phase so it's only a couple of internal users at present.

What's going on, and is there a way around it?

I'm also concerned because we have an existing product out in the field, and are due to release a new version shortly. I'm panicking that all these users will lose their settings and preferences when they upgrade.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429558/c-sharp-net-application-settings-and-upgrading

Comment: @Caramiriel thanks and apologies. On this occasion I didn't search for similar questions before posting mine!

Comment: No problem, sometimes it's hard to find the right keywords to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on other SO questions and articles found on the web, I've written this short method that I now call during application startup:

```
    private static void CheckForUserSettingsUpgrade()
    {
        if (!Properties.Settings.Default.UserSettingsUpgradeRequired)
        {
            return;
        }

        Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
        Properties.Settings.Default.UserSettingsUpgradeRequired = false;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

For this to work there must be a user-scope setting called `UserSettingsUpgradeRequired` with a default value of `True`.

After an upgrade (resulting in a new settings file being created) this setting's value will of course be *true*. In this scenario the above code will import all settings from the previous settings file (if any), set this upgrade flag setting to false, then save the changes. After the next upgrade, the flag's value will revert to true, and the process will repeat itself.